# F5 in VBA cannot show the result or showing the wrong result, but F8 shows the correct result

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use VBA to extract some date from another worksheets, and when i run the code line by line, it shows the correct result. but if i run it at a whole, it simply not work without any error...

Anyone has ideas why this happened? Thanks

Below is my code:

```
Sub UpdateOriginalProjectEnd()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsTable1 As Worksheet, wsTable2 As Worksheet
    Dim lastRowTable1 As Long, lastRowTable2 As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim ppmNumber As String
    Dim matchingRecords As Range
    Dim smallestDateSequence As Double
    Dim originalProjectEnd As Range
    Dim latestPLDate As String
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsTable1 = wb.Worksheets("JUN-JUL 23") ' Update with the actual worksheet name for Table 1
    Set wsTable2 = wb.Worksheets("Project Date (2)") ' Update with the actual worksheet name for Table 2
    
    ' Find the last row in Table 1
    lastRowTable1 = wsTable1.Cells(wsTable1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Loop through Table 1
    For i = 2 To lastRowTable1
        ppmNumber = Right(wsTable1.Cells(i, "D").Value, 4) ' Get the last 4 digits of PPM# in Table 1
        
        ' Find matching records in Table 2 based on PPMID
        Set matchingRecords = wsTable2.Range("B:B").Find(What:=ppmNumber, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        
        If Not matchingRecords Is Nothing Then
            ' Find records with "LastCycle" in column "A"
            Dim lastCycleRecords As Range
            Set lastCycleRecords = wsTable2.Range("A:A").Find(What:="LastCycle", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            
            If Not lastCycleRecords Is Nothing Then
                ' Initialize variables
                smallestDateSequence = 99999999999# ' Set a large initial value
                latestPLDate = DateValue("1/1/1900") ' Set a low initial value
                
                lastRowTable2 = wsTable2.Cells(wsTable2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                For j = 2 To lastRowTable2
                    If wsTable2.Cells(j, "B").Value = ppmNumber And wsTable2.Cells(j, "A").Value = "LastCycle" Then
                        Dim currentSequence As Double
                        currentSequence = CDbl(Right(wsTable2.Cells(j, "C").Value, 11)) ' Get the last 11 digits of DateSequence
                                      
                        If currentSequence <> smallestDateSequence Then
                            smallestDateSequence = currentSequence ' Update the smallestDateSequence
                        
                            ' Find the last row within the same DateSequence group
                            Dim lastRowSameSequence As Long
                            lastRowSameSequence = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("C:C"), wsTable2.Cells(j, "C").Value)
                            Dim k As Long
                            Dim PLDate As String
                            
                            For k = j To j + lastRowSameSequence - 1
                                If wsTable2.Cells(k, "B").Value = ppmNumber And wsTable2.Cells(k, "A").Value = "LastCycle" And CDbl(Right(wsTable2.Cells(k, "C").Value, 11)) = currentSequence Then
                                    If wsTable2.Cells(k, "G").Value <> "" Then
                                        ' Compare "PLDate" to find the latest
                                        If wsTable2.Cells(k, "G").Value > PLDate And latestPLDate = DateValue("1/1/1900") Then
                                            PLDate = wsTable2.Cells(k, "G").Value ' Update the latest PLDate
                                        End If
                                    End If
                                End If
                            Next k
                            
                            ' Update the latestPLDate if a non-blank PLDate was found
                            If PLDate > latestPLDate Then
                                latestPLDate = PLDate ' Update the latestPLDate
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                Next j
                
                If smallestDateSequence = 99999999999# Then
                    ' No records found with non-blank "PLDate", set "Original Project End" as "N/A"
                    wsTable1.Cells(i, "G").Value = "N/A"
                ElseIf latestPLDate > DateValue("1/1/1900") Then
                    ' Copy the latest "PLDate" to Table 1 "Original Project End"
                    Set originalProjectEnd = wsTable1.Cells(i, "G")
                    originalProjectEnd.Value = latestPLDate
                End If
            Else
                ' No records found with "LastCycle", set "Original Project End" as "N/A"
                wsTable1.Cells(i, "G").Value = "N/A"
            End If
        latestPLDate = DateValue("1/1/1900")
        PLDate = ""
        Else
            wsTable1.Cells(i, "G").Value = "N/A"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image: This is how my data looks like]

I just expect the VBA should be working

Comment: Usually means an unqualified range/cell... and here's one in your code.... `.CountIf(Range("C:C")`

Comment: The code should produce the same result with F5 or F8. Verify the active sheet is consistent. Explicitly reference sheets for all ranges like `Range("C:C")`.

Comment: The reason F5 doesn't do the same thing is that the active sheet can change when you are stepping through it, depending on where the code is.

Comment: I found that when i run the code very fast, it just skip my code below :
If wsTable2.Cells(k, "B").Value = ppmNumber And wsTable2.Cells(k, "A").Value = "LastCycle" And CDbl(Right(wsTable2.Cells(k, "C").Value, 11)) = currentSequence Then
but if i press F8 slowly, the VBA could identify this is true and go to the next step...

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.
Becasue I found out that when I execute the code in Table 2 sheet, it works!
But when I execute the code in table 1 sheet, it just cannot show the result.
So, I simply added:

```
wsTable2.Select
```

Before

```
Set matchingRecords = wsTable2.Range("B:B").Find(What:=ppmNumber, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
```

And DONE!!!!
Thanks you